# How to checked only one radio button dynamically using Angular

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to check only one radio button at a time but right now I checked multiple radio buttons

**HTML**

```
<td class="ci-prim-para ci-txt-left ci-p-5 width40">
   <p class="ci-pr-5">{{arc.node_value}}</p>
</td>
<td class="ci-prim-para ci-txt-left ci-p-5 width15">
  <ion-radio color="tertiary" slot="start" [value]="arc.node_id"></ion-radio>
</td>
```

Comment: add class to radio and determine it by class

Comment: How to determine? Any Example?